# SQL lock row,table on insert and select

Tags: sql

I am trying to achieve some sort of lock on sql.
To explain what am i doing simple:
One table with Id int autoincrement as PK, and one field Data varchar(max) non-clustered IX

Now i have some C# code that simlpy checks if the item isn't in the db, makes an insert
The sql code that i am using behind is like:

```
INSERT INTO {0}.{1} WITH (TABLOCKX) VALUES(@data...)
```

and the select one is:

```
SELECT Id FROM {0}.{1} WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE(Data = @data)
```

But i can see that there are items with the same value inserted multiple times
TABLOCK creates deadlocks, and i dont want to use unique index because its very slow.

Is there a way to achieve this with locking?

Comment: you could put a unique constraint against the column within your db this would prevent the same value being inserted when it already exists

Comment: SQL server 2008, and MarkD, i dont want to use unique index

Comment: in your insert statement where are you checking that the result doesn't already exist in the table?

Comment: I am doing that in application code as i mentioned above, first executing the "select" and if get no data i use the "insert"

Comment: An easy and reliable way is to add a unique constraint and catch "duplicate key" errors

Comment: I don't see why you should not run this in a `TRANSACTION`, and leave the locking behaviour to the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is what you want, I hope that this reply is helpful.

```
private void test(string aConnectionString, string aData)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(aConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
            sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction;

            try
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandText = @"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM {0}.{1} WHERE Data = @Data)
                                           BEGIN
                                                INSERT INTO {0}.{1}
                                                SELECT @Data
                                           END";

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Data", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = aData;
                sqlTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sqlTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```